# What are the signs that my cat is not happy playing with my toddler son?

Tags: cats, behavior, safety, stress, children

My cat (Fluffy) has his own territory of raised platform with good window viewing, plus many other areas where my 2 year old son (Hugo) has generally restricted access or not permitted.

Fluffy is a 5 year old Norwegian Forest Cat. We currently have a 2 metre long box in the kitchen and Fluffy camps in at times. The play is Fluffy runs in one end and Hugo chases him. Fluffy runs out and then back in. In other places, whether Hugo chases Fluffy if he wants to get away, then we let him through a door (Hugo can't pass) to upstairs. So far with the box-play Fluffy doesn't do that, but what other signs might I look for that he stressed by the "play"?

Fluffy is pretty nice - he plays for a few minutes a day biting a doll.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok some signs are that the cat would be slashing his tail around if he didn't like the playing. You may see whiskers pointed forward as a sign to attack or scare Hugo. Or ears to the back if he was to be afraid of him. But if I got you right you said Fluffy returns to the box to continue playing? If that's so then you wouldn't need to worry. He may actually like the playing. If Fluffy runs very fast however, and does not come back to Hugo this means he's afraid of him and wishes to have his space.

This answer is based on what I got out of your question, I hope it helped.

Comment: I only want to add, that it xould be different, if the cat try to defend this box. Maybe then it would not go away to get peace so easily? I am not a cat person, so it is an assumtion, that cats may defend their own goods?

Comment: This is mostly good, but a cat's whiskers being pointed forward are not a sign of aggression; they're a sign of excitement, and their whiskers being forward vs back is a good barometer of their attitude of "play" vs "aggression," in exactly the opposite way described in this answer. Forward whiskers = play, excitement; whiskers pinned back = anger, aggression, fear.